# How do i predict one of the moderator variables in my linear meta-regression?

Tags: r, linear-regression, metafor

I have created a linear meta-regression in the metafor package:

```
res <- rma(LnRR, sei=StdError, mods = ~ LVEF, data=HF_data)
```

I can predict LnRR for a given LVEF using the folllowing function:

```
predict(res, newmods = 50, transf = exp, addx = TRUE)
```

How do I estimate the LVEF for a given LnRR?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please share a dput() of your data so others can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your `predict()` statement is estimating the **exponentiated** predicted value of LnRR, not LnRR itself (since you use `transf=exp`).

Answer (score 0):

The fitted model is simply yhat = b0 + b1 * x, so if you want to know what value of x produces a particular predicted value yhat, you can just compute (yhat - b0) / b1. A reproducible example:

```
> library(metafor)
> dat <- escalc(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat.bcg)
> res <- rma(yi, vi, mods = ~ ablat, data=dat)
> predict(res, newmod=30)

    pred     se   ci.lb   ci.ub   pi.lb   pi.ub
 -0.6216 0.1069 -0.8312 -0.4120 -1.2023 -0.0409

> (predict(res, newmod=30)$pred - coef(res)[[1]]) / coef(res)[[2]]
[1] 30
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Where in that code do i enter my given yhat? Only variable I can change is where you entered 30, so the code returns the same value.

Comment: `predict(res, newmod=30)$pred` is the yhat value. I am showing that if you would use this value for yhat, then you indeed get the 30 back. But of course you can plug in any other yhat value.

Comment: Sorry, could you give me an example code. If i wanted to estiamte the ablat value when yi = 1 for example?

Comment: `(1 - coef(res)[[1]]) / coef(res)[[2]]`

Comment: Hi Wolfgang. Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to estimate the ablat value when pi.ub = 0?